# Scheme: a good set function

Tags: scheme, computer-science, racket

I need to write a good set function that checks whether its argument `lst` is a properly represented set, i.e. it is a list consisting only of integers, with no duplicates, and returns true #t or false #f. For example:

```
(good-set? (1 5 2)) => #t

(good-set? ()) => #t

(good-set? (1 5 5)) => #f

(good-set? (1 (5) 2)) => #f
```

so I have began writing the function as:

```
(define (good-set? lst)
```

so I don't know how to proceed after this. Can anybody help?

Comment: Use `(andmap integer? lst)` to find out whether all elements are integers. Use `check-duplicate` to check whether there are any duplicates. As an alternative: The elements are unique if `(= (length lst) (set-count (list->set lst)))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to use `andmap` and sets, as has been suggested by @soegaard:

```
(define (good-set? lst)                  ; it's a good set if:
  (and (andmap integer? lst)             ; all its elements are integers and
       (= (length lst)                   ; the list's length equals the size
          (set-count (list->set lst))))) ; of a set with the same elements
```

But if you can't use sets or other advanced procedures, then traverse the list and test if the current element is an integer and is not present somewhere else in the list (use [`member`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket/private/list..rkt%29._member%29%29) for this), repeating this test for each element until there are no more elements in the list. Here's the general idea, fill-in the blanks:

```
(define (good-set? lst)
  (cond (<???>                ; if the list is empty
         <???>)               ; then it's a good set
        ((or <???>            ; if the 1st element is not an integer or
             <???>)           ; the 1st element is in the rest of the list
         <???>)               ; then it's NOT a good set
        (else                 ; otherwise
         (good-set? <???>)))) ; advance recursion
```

Answer (score 1):

Sets are [built into](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/sets.html) the Racket standard library: I would recommend not reimplementing them in terms of lists unless you really need to do something customized.

---

If we need to treat this as a homework assignment, I would recommend using a design methodology to systematically attack this problem.  In this case, see something like [How to Design Programs](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/matthias/HtDP2e/part_two.html#%28part._ch~3adesign-lists%29) with regards to designing functions that work on lists.  As a brief sketch, we'd systematically figure out:

- What's the structure of the data I'm working with?
- What tests cases do I consider?  (including the base case)
- What's the overall shape of the function?
- What's the meaning of the `natural recursion`?
- How do I combine the result of the `natural recursion` in order to compute a solution to the total?

Answer (score 1):

For this, check if the first number is duplicated, if it is not, then recurse by checking the rest.  As such:

```
(define (good-set? list)
  (or (null? list)                      ; nothing left, good!
      (let ((head (car list)))
            (rest (cdr list)))
        (and (number? head)             ; a number
             (not (member = head rest)) ; not in the rest
             (good-set? rest)))))       ; check the rest
```

If you need `member`, then

```
(define (member pred item list)
  (and (not (null? list))
       (or (pred item (car list))
           (member pred item (cdr list)))))
```